# AngularJS - Manual compile directive which require parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to manual compile directive which requires some others directive controller.

F.E.

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
   require: '^otherDirective',
   ...
 });
```

in some other directive linking function I'm doing:

```
var newElement = $compile('<my-directive>')(scope);
element.replaceWith(newElement);
//element is of course children of "otherDirective".
```

It gives me error: 
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'otherDirective', required by directive 'myDirective', can't be found!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Since `myDirective` *requires* `otherDirective`, the only way I see is wrapping the compilation, i.e. `$compile('<other-directive><my-directive></other-directive>')(scope)` or revising your design.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: What do you mean by reversing my design?
What I want achive is to conditonaly apply myDirective inside ng-repeat.

Comment: It's "revising", not "reversing". You probably have to provide more information about the specific use case.

Comment: did you have any luck with this btw?